# Reinstall paid software from USC in Kubuntu

Tags: software-center, kubuntu

I've bought Psychonauts via USC some time ago. I've switched to Kubuntu now and want to reinstall the game. Whats the best way to do so, without installing too many otherwise unnecessary packages?

Answer (score 0):

Just re-install it - how ever that software is installed.

If it is a deb then all the dependencies can be automatically loaded via apt-get install.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu Software Center (software-center package), as for now, paid apps can only be installed using it.